# BIRT report with parameters: Can not load the report query

Tags: jboss, report, birt, viewer

I'm trying to run a report on Birt web viewer (JBoss) with a parameter and I get the following error:

```
- Grid (id = 1461):
+ Can not load the report query: 1461. Errors occurred when generating the report document for the report element with ID 1,461. (Element ID:1461)
```

Reports without parameters are working fine. Reports with parameters are running fine in Eclipse Report Designer.

Could someone give me advice please?

Answer (score 1):

I had same kind a problem (ie. the report was throwing error while tried to fetch from the tomcat web container). To resolve this issue, I have added the database driver in the `/WEB-INF/lib folder`.

Please try this once and let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem opening my report with "preview" instead of "frameset". This shows the real exception.

Answer (score 0):

Might be you have not define id in your report parameter,either in report parameter or data set parameter.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the datasource for BIRT was not configured correctly. I needed to make sure the JNDI name matched what was in the config for my container.